# How to write algorithms/functions as in my picture

Tags: packages, algorithms

I've found some rather nice slides and I was wondering whether anyone knows which package/settings are used to get something like this:
[image: example]

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe ask the author?

Comment: There are several packages for typesetting algorithms and functions, and a good starting point similar to the above is the [algorithm2e](http://mirror.ox.ac.uk/sites/ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/algorithm2e/doc/algorithm2e.pdf) package, where section 4 presents function similar to yours.

Comment: @oliversm If you expand your comment with an example on how to using algorith2e, you comment will be a nice answer.

Comment: @Sveinung the examples I've pointed to should suffice. Also, given there is no MWE in the OP it would be a good starting point for them.